# disable anchor link '<a>' if one of my six checkboxes are not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, disable

How can I ***disable*** a ***anchor link*** if one(1) of my six(6) checkbox is not check?

```
    var first_option = $('#pid-1590083, #pid-1590090, #pid-1590091, #pid-1590092, #pid-1590093, #pid-1590094');

        $("a").click(function(e) {
       if($("first_option").prop("checked") === false) {
        e.preventDefault(); return false;
       } else {return true;};
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the answers you provided guys, I fixed it ---> https://codepen.io/georgie-veloso/pen/yRMzww

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic doesn't work as you're only looking at the `checked` property of the first element you select, not all of them.

To achieve what you require, you can use the `:checked` selector to get all the checked elements within the selectors you provide, then check the `length` property of the result to see if there aren't any. Try this:

```js
var $first_option = $('#pid-1590083, #pid-1590090, #pid-1590091, #pid-1590092, #pid-1590093, #pid-1590094');

$("#tmp_button-99035").click(function(e) {
  if ($first_option.filter(':checked').length === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Please Choose Collar Colour To Continue');
  };
});
```

Comment: how about it's not a button, it's a anchor link to disable. disable a anchor link if one of the six checkbox is not check

Comment: I found this code but unable to work with multiple checkbox 

' $("a").click(function(e) {
    if($("#checkBox").prop("checked") === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    };
}); '

Comment: This logic will also work fine with an `a` element. If you're struggling it would help to see a full example of your issue. Could you please edit the question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Thank you Rory, already corrected my my mistake and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`first_option.prop("checked")` will always check for first element. What you have to do is loop over all elements to check

Like this

```
$("#tmp_button-99035").click(function(e) {
    var isChecked = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < first_option.length; i++) {
        if (first_option.eq(i).prop("checked")) {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isChecked) {
        alert('Please Choose Collar Colour To Continue');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return isChecked;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the js snippet of yours is only checking the first element. So, you have to track other checkboxes as well for correct result.

```
var first_option = $('#pid-1590083, #pid-1590090, #pid-1590091, #pid-1590092, #pid-1590093, #pid-1590094')

$(document).on('click', '#tmp_button-99035', function (e) {
    if ($(first_option).filter(":checked").length == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```